# kubectl get all returns lots of forbidden error using rancher permission

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

I use rancher to manager the k8s cluster to allow only access some specific project/namespace, it works good except it gots annoying error messages

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-64cf74bdcb-vmssn           1/1     Running   0          14m

NAME                    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/nginx           NodePort   10.100.132.26           80:32318/TCP   14m

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx           1/1     1            1           14m

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-contiki-64cf74bdcb   1         1         1       14m
Error from server (Forbidden): users.jenkins.io is forbidden: User "u-4foykbynfi" cannot list resource "users" in API group "jenkins.io" in the namespace "sandbox"
Error from server (Forbidden): facts.jenkins.io is forbidden: User "u-4foykbynfi" cannot list resource "facts" in API group "jenkins.io" in the namespace "sandbox"
...
```

This user just wants to check the all resource on its own namespace, though it doesn't have permission to other API group, but can we just skip this check?

How can I configure in rancher or k8s to not show this error msg (or exit code)

env

- k8s server - v1.14.1
- kubectl client - v1.13.2
- rancher - v2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you invoke `kubectl get all` command, k8s looks through resources catalog bounded to `all` category. You can add this category for each custom object [*CRD*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#create-a-customresourcedefinition), supplying particular `CustomResourceDefinition` resource definition as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#categories).

However, you can't change the `kubectl get` command approach, you may apply only certain filters or customize printed output.

If your aim only with getting output of `kubectl get all` to `stdout` avoiding error records, you can probably redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` :

```
$ kubectl get all 2>/dev/null
```

Or even fetch exit code for the previous command via `echo $?`.

You can also add `--as` flag to `kubectl get` command in order to impersonate resource owner:

```
$ kubectl get all --as=<username>
```